# Base table or view not found for faker Database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web

***I have Error in Laravel***

When us `$ php artisan db:seed` in git 
Error is :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'noor_app.noors' doesn'
>   t exist (SQL: insert into `noors` (`title`, `description`, `completed`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Voluptates fac
>   ilis velit repellat., Iure facere dolore ea earum. Temporibus nesciunt minima eos., 0, 2020-02-07 02:11:12, 2020-02-07 02:
>   11:12))

**information in mysql**
my Database called : `noor_app`
my tables called : 
`failed_jobs`-`migrations`-`noor`-`password_resets`-`users`

factories files is :
noorFactory.php
UserFactory.php

**this is** `noorFactory.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class noorSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\noor::class , 10)->create();

    }
}
```

**migrations file**
**this is** `2020_02_06_000033_create_noor_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateNoorTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('noor', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->boolean('completed');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('noor');
    }
}
```

**speed file**
**this is** `noorSpeeder.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class noorSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\noor::class , 10)->create();

    }
}
```

**speed file**
**this is** `DatabaseSpeeder.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
       $this->call(noorSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

**Providers file**
**this is** `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Providers file**
**this is** `noor.php`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class noor extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**how to fixed this Error to make faker Database**
 
**And thank you**

Comment: Also show ‘noor’ model what is inside

Answer (score 1):

Rename table in mysql to ‘noors’ and adjust models and migrations properly, according to new table name.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel Conventions**

> By convention, the "snake case", **plural name** of the class will be used
>   as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in
>   this case, Eloquent will assume the noor model stores records in the
>   noors table.

However If you want to stick to current table name 'noor', you may specify a custom table by defining a table property on your model:

```
protected $table = 'noor';
```